# MP3, firefox, email, javascript, jplayer

Tags: flash, firefox, mp3, jplayer, ogg

i want to play audio 2 ways

1. Through my website (easier, as i can detect the browser)
2. sending an email which will have a player to stream the audio

restrictions.
1. Firefox wont play MP3
2. Iphone/ipad wont play flash
3. Iphone/ipad wont play ogg
4. Emails have trouble with javascript -jplayer (potential of ending in the trash)

problem.
if i send via an email, i cant detect the browser, so cant choose ogg, flash, etc.

Solutions
1. Use HTML 5 and embed a player stream mp3... works in iphone, ie8, chrome....not in firefox (mp3 issue) and older ie browsers (html5 issue).

1. use jplayer.... i expect the email to dislike the javascript and throw into the trash, plus will firefox play the mp3 audio?
2. use flash.... i expect iphone/ipad not to work, also will it play from an email?

what is the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the older IE browsers bit, you could just use HTML5 and point to both MP3 and Vorbis sources; the browser will pick the one it can play.

Comment: how do i point to both ogg and mp3, once the email is constructed and sent, how does it detect the browser..

Comment: @user665782 You can use two `<source>` elements inside the `<audio>`, pointing to the two files, with the correct `type` attributes.  You don't need to detect the browser: just tell it about both files, and it will play the one it knows how to play.